# Group rows by the value of a column and calculate median in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I am struggling with this issue: I have a matrix (ClHM) which has 64 rows and 22 columns. Column number 22 has values from 1 to 12 that represent groups within the matrix. I want to produce a new matrix with the groups specified in column 22 as rows and the median of the members of the group for each one of the other columns.

I got the farthest with this:

aggregate(ClHM, by = as.list(ClHM[,22]), median)

But it keeps returning:
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

I don't understand how they can have different lenghts when ClHM[,22] is a column within ClHM.

Thank you very much for your help! And I am sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: Try `aggregate(ClHM, by = list(ClHM[,22]), median)`  or just `aggregate(ClHM, by = ClHM[22], median)`  the `as.list` converts the vector in to a `list of elements.  instead we need a list column which can be either done by extractig as a vector as you showed and then wrap with `list` or have a data.frame with one column `ClHM[22]`

Comment: To understsand it better, try this on your console `as.list(1:5)` and `list(1:5)`.  In the former case, it is a list of length 5 and in the latter a list of length 1 with the element having a length 5

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you so much!!! :)